# Is it possible to force Inventor Design Automation to update all views in a drawing before outputting to pdf?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

I've run into an issue with a Forge configurator that we are developing, whereby the pdf output does not reflect the configured model.

The general process that it follows is it opens the assembly, and sets the level of detail of various sub-assemblies to match user configured options. It then saves the assembly and opens a drawing that references it. From there it generates a pdf output.
The problem is that the views do not show the levels of detail that have been set on the model components. So I'm wondering if there is a way to force an update before outputting the pdf?

I have found a work around which works for small models (e.g. 57 components, total size 26MB) which is to suppress and then un-suppress every drawing view on every sheet, plus calling sheet.Update(). But unfortunately this does not work for the large models (e.g. 514 components, total size 287MB) that this system is designed to work with. This does however work when run locally, just doesn't work on Forge, where it appears as if it hasn't had time to show the drawing views again before creating the pdf, as they are all blank.

Tried in Inventor 2020, 2021, and 2022 with the same results.

Thanks in advance for any help that you can give.

Comment: Hello, In order to help you with your problem we need to analyze it first. In order to do that we would like to ask you to provide your smaller dataset and also the source code to your AppBundle used to export the PDF. Please send those data to michal.vasicek@autodesk.com

Comment: As Michal suggested, it will be helpful to have a reproducible dataset for us to diagnose. you can also send it to forge.help @autodesk.com.  In addition,  I am curious how it goes if you run the workflow in local Inventor.

Comment: Hi Michal and Xiaodong, I will just need to check with the customer to make sure we can send you the dataset. The workflow works correctly if run on local Inventor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your dataset we found out that your filenames use diacritics and your ZIP file doesn't use UTF-8 encoding. This produces bad characters in your filenames when Forge server un-zip it. Therefore Inventor Server indicates ‘**Unresolved Files**’ status when  a drawing/assembly is loaded with such filenames.  How to solve this problem is described in the Forge Design Automation documentation, navigate to ['Troubleshooting'](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/troubleshooting/) page and look into '**Non-English filenames in ZIP files**' paragraph.